# Split a string to have individual quotes

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string

`abc = 'tea,coffee'`

Want to split into **('tea','coffee')**

I tried to split but the result is showing as double quotes in front and last 
i am getting result as `"tea','coffee"`

Comment: Please share the code you've used. If you're working on the IDLE interpreter, are you sure you're printing the strings correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#given string
abc = 'tea,coffee'

#splitting into array
result = abc.split(',')

#making tuple
tuple(result)

#printing result
print(result)
```

> done!!

Comment: This will return a list, need to  have the output as string  'tea','coffee' , so i can pass this to a sql  parameter in clause

Comment: upvote my answer if you found solution